# Xlookup of value based in text and in-between dates, searching 1 (true) from condition range

Tags: google-sheets

Please help me to come up with the ARRAYFORMULA equivalent of the following formula that works perfectly when copied to every row:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2), "", ARRAYFORMULA(
   XLOOKUP(1,(B2=G:G)*(A2>=H:H)*(A2<=I:I),
   J:J,"NON-HOTSPOT")))
```

I have tried the following but it returned an `#N/A` error, meaning it didn't find the right data:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",
   XLOOKUP(1,(B2:B=G:G)*(A2:A>=H:H)*(A2:A<=I:I),
   J:J,"NON-HOTSPOT")))
```

[Link to sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QwynZdK3cNejJ6KGU5SlQ2jjoZlta5Aq1Qle-S9LzD4/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Column C and D for the formula]

[image: Columns for the Text and Dates condition]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map()`, like this:

```
=map(A2:A, B2:B, lambda(date, loc, 
  iferror(arrayformula( 
    xlookup(1, (loc = G2:G) * (H2:H <= date) * (date <= I2:I), J2:J, "NON-HOTSPOT") 
  )) 
))
```

See [map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985).